# Matplotlib multiprocessing fonts corruption using savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I have troubles with multiprocessing in Matplotlib since version 1.5.  The fonts are randomly jumping around their original position. Example is here:
[image]

The simple example to reproduce this bug is here:

```
import multiprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

def plot(i):
    fig = plt.gcf()
    plt.plot([],[])
    fig.savefig('%d.png' % i)

plot(0)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
pool.map(plot, range(10))
```

if the order of multiprocessing and simple plotting is reversed

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
plot(0)
pool.map(plot, range(10))
```

then it works, but this workaround is useless for my purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: You are assuming that concurrent access to the plotting logic is safe. I would be rather surprised if it actually is.

Comment: Probably it is not, but it was working with older matplotlib and it is working sometimes with the new as well. I just need a way how to create and save plots by multiprocessing.

Comment: Drawing plots is very similar to paintings in real life. Having multiple artists  often does not improve the result. :)

Comment: Yes, I know, but it was working with the older matplotlib version, and it is working also if multiprocessing is done before a standard plotting.I believe that this a key to find the solution.  But I do not understood why. Is there some quantity or variable which is changed when a plot is created? Is it possible to do a "fresh start" of matplotlib? I have tried to do plotting without pylab, but the result was the same.

Comment: up to  now I have found just one ugly workaround, I have to call savefig (or actually draw inside savefig) always outside of main threat 

 Process(target=fig.savefig,args=(name,)).start()

but it is not always possible.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently run into this same problem while testing methods for parallel plotting large numbers of plots.  While I haven't found a solution using the multiprocessing module, I've found that I do not see the same errors using the Parallel Python package (http://www.parallelpython.com/). It seems to be ~50% slower than the multiprocessing module in my early tests, but still a significant speedup over serial plotting. It's also a little finicky regarding module imports so I would ultimately prefer to find a solution using multiprocessing, but for now this is a passable workaround (for me at least).  That said, I'm pretty new to parallel processing so there may be some nuances of the two approaches that I'm missing here.

```
###############################################################################
import os
import sys
import time
#import numpy as np
import numpy    # Importing with 'as' doesn't work with Parallel Python
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot    # Importing with 'as' doesn't work with Parallel Python
import pp
import multiprocessing as mp
###############################################################################
path1='./Test_PP'
path2='./Test_MP'
nplots=100
###############################################################################
def plotrandom(plotid,N,path):
    numpy.random.seed() # Required for multiprocessing module but not Parallel Python...
    x=numpy.random.randn(N)
    y=x**2
    matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x,y)
    matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(os.path.join(path,'test_%d.png'%(plotid)),dpi=150)
    matplotlib.pyplot.close('all')
##############################################################################    #
# Parallel Python implementation
tstart_1=time.time()
if not os.path.exists(path1):
    os.makedirs(path1)

ppservers = ()

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    ncpus = int(sys.argv[1])
    job_server = pp.Server(ncpus, ppservers=ppservers)
else:
    job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers)

print "Starting Parallel Python v2 with", job_server.get_ncpus(), "workers"

jobs = [(input_i, job_server.submit(plotrandom,(input_i,10,path1),(),("numpy","matplotlib.pyplot"))) for input_i in range(nplots)]

for input_i, job in jobs:
    job()

tend_1=time.time()
t1=tend_1-tstart_1
print 'Parallel Python = %0.5f sec'%(t1)
job_server.print_stats()
##############################################################################    #
# Multiprocessing implementation
tstart_2=time.time()
if not os.path.exists(path2):
    os.makedirs(path2)

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    ncpus = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    ncpus = mp.cpu_count()

print "Starting multiprocessing v2 with %d workers"%(ncpus)

pool = mp.Pool(processes=ncpus)
jobs = [pool.apply_async(plotrandom, args=(i,10,path2)) for i in range(nplots)]
results = [r.get() for r in jobs]    # This line actually runs the jobs
pool.close()
pool.join()

tend_2=time.time()
t2=tend_2-tstart_2
print 'Multiprocessing = %0.5f sec'%(t2)
###############################################################################
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. The main cause of the troubles is the font caching in dictionary _fontd in  /matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py

Therefore, I have used a different hash for each process by adding  multiprocessing.current_process().pid to hash called *key* in function _get_agg_font.

If anybody know more elegant solution which would not require modification of matplotlib files, just let me know.

Comment: Can you please detail a little bit more? I am not familiar enough with backend...

Comment: Can you add more detail to you answer here with an example code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Here is shown how I changed function **_get_agg_font** in **backend_agg.py**:

```
from multiprocessing import current_process
def _get_agg_font(self, prop):
    """
    Get the font for text instance t, cacheing for efficiency
    """
    if __debug__: verbose.report('RendererAgg._get_agg_font',
                                 'debug-annoying')

    key = hash(prop)
    key += current_process().pid

    font = RendererAgg._fontd.get(key)

    if font is None:
        fname = findfont(prop)
        #font = RendererAgg._fontd.get(fname)
        if font is None:
            font = FT2Font(
                fname,
                hinting_factor=rcParams['text.hinting_factor'])
            RendererAgg._fontd[fname] = font
        RendererAgg._fontd[key] = font

    font.clear()
    size = prop.get_size_in_points()
    font.set_size(size, self.dpi)

    return font
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to place your matplotlib imports *inside* the function you're passing to multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: Concurrent use of cached fonts created glitches in text plots (e.g. axes numbers).  The problems appears to be font caching by an lru cache:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/7b6eb77731ff2b58c43c0d75a9cc038ada8d89cd/lib/matplotlib/font_manager.py#L1316

For me upgrading to python 3.7 solved it (which apparently supports cleaning state after forking).

Running the following in your workers might help as well:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.font_manager._get_font.cache_clear()
```

Comment: I have been trying to solve this problem for YEARS. Putting this as the first lines of my plotting function finally solved it. Welcome to stack overflow Oliver--great first post!